# JSON returning null values on response

Tags: java, json, web-services, jackson

My `response` is giving me `null` values, but when I'm running the same in `fiddler`, I get a lot of data. I have written very less code and used online tools to generate my code. I wonder where I am messing up.

```
    Publications response = null ;
    // First open URL connection (using JDK; similar with other libs)
    try {
        URL url = new URL(
                "http://myserver:myport/Mobile/GetPublications");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection() ;
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST") ;
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json") ;
        // and other configuration if you want, timeouts etc
        // then send JSON request
        Publications request = new Publications(); // POJO with getters or public fields
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
        mapper.writeValue(connection.getOutputStream(), request);
        // and read response
        response = mapper.readValue(
                connection.getInputStream(), Publications.class);
    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail() ;
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail() ;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail() ;
    }
    assertNotNull(response) ;
    assertTrue(response.getPublicationInfo() != null) ;
//      assertTrue(response.getPublicationInfo().size() > 0);
//      assertNotNull( ((PublicationInfo)response.getPublicationInfo().get(0)).getPublicationTitle() != null) ;
```

And the Publications POJO is

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.*

@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@Generated("com.googlecode.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "ErrorInfo", "PublicationInfo" })
public class Publications {

@JsonProperty("ErrorInfo")
private Object ErrorInfo;

@JsonProperty("PublicationInfo")
private List<PublicationInfo> PublicationInfo = new ArrayList<PublicationInfo>();
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonProperty("ErrorInfo")
public Object getErrorInfo() {
    return ErrorInfo;
}

@JsonProperty("ErrorInfo")
public void setErrorInfo(Object ErrorInfo) {
    this.ErrorInfo = ErrorInfo;
}

@JsonProperty("PublicationInfo")
public List<PublicationInfo> getPublicationInfo() {
    return PublicationInfo;
}

@JsonProperty("PublicationInfo")
public void setPublicationInfo(
        List<PublicationInfo> PublicationInfo) {
    this.PublicationInfo = PublicationInfo;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperties(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
}
```

I get a test case failure at `assertTrue(response.getPublicationInfo().size() > 0);`. But fiddler returns the following

```
{
"SpecialPublications": {
    "ErrorInfo": null,
    "SpecialPublicationInfo": [
        {
            "Date": "2/3/2010",
            "URL": "SOME URL HERE",
            "Description": "So much to do so less time."
        },
        {
            "Date": "2/4/2010",
            "URL": "SOME MORE URL HERE",
            "Description": "I need more time"
        }
   ]
}
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you first determine if you actually got a response -- before JSON parsing.

Comment: SpotlightPublicationInfo != PublicationInfo? Where are you mapping the latter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change `@JsonProperty("PublicationInfo")` to `@JsonProperty("SpotlightPublicationInfo")` in all places. You got the attribute name wrong.

The semantics of `@JsonProperty` is: the attribute name as it appears in the json.

**EDIT** Also strip the spurious attribute name from the json. Replace:

```
response = mapper.readValue(connection.getInputStream(), Publications.class);
```

With:

```
JsonNode responseJson = mapper.readTree(connection.getInputStream());
response = mapper.readValue(responseJson.traverse().getValueAsString("SpecialPublications"), Publications.class);
```

This will strip out the spurious `{"SpecialPublications": ... }` wrapper of the object you try to parse.

Comment: I did this change, and still I have the same issue. The junit test does not pass and fiddler returns a whole truck load of data.

Comment: @taxeeta: yes there is one more reason for that. Your code will work if the json was without the `{"SpecialPublications": ... }` wrapper. Let me think of what will be the easiest way to remove it. Will it be an option if you always remove it via regex?

Comment: @taxeeta Here goes my suggestion. Please, write back if I did any error, because I have written it only in the text editor, have not tried it myself.

Comment: I am getting a `The method readValue(JsonParser, Class<T>) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (JsonNode, Class<Publications>)` eclipse error, complier error.

Comment: Also I repalced `get` with `getValueAsString`. I'll try it out on Monday and respond back. Thanks.

Comment: @taxeeta is it for the json you have provided?